# Read HTML in Progress4GL

Tags: html, xml, openedge, progress-4gl

Is there a library or a way to read HTML files in Progress4GL?
I want to read a HTML file specifically a `<table>` tag within in, and capture that data as a list of items in a temp-table.

[This website](http://convertcsv.com/html-table-to-csv.htm) offers a way of converting the HTML table to a CSV file, but if possible I want to do this within my ABL session.

Comment: I'd look for a utility to extract the table to csv json or xml and process that. you can call external commands with os-command or input through

Answer (score -1):

I eventually found a solution to this by using the `INPUT STREAM FROM` statement and creating a temp-table record for each line of the HTML file.

https://help.consultingwerkcloud.com/openedge/117/rfi1424920545278.html

Comment: That you can read a text file using the input statement is not a solution for how to extract a table from an html document.